# How to use multiple values for one variable depending on the result of an if-else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

In the code sample below I want to make it so that `deductions` would equal one of the 4 values depending on the input the user enters (look at the if-else statement). Is this possible?

```
deductions1 = 0.12 + 0.04 + 0.01 + 0.06
deductions2 = 0.20 + 0.07 + 0.03 + 0.06
deductions3 = 0.30 + 0.09 + 0.05 + 0.06
deductions4 = 0.38 + 0.11 + 0.07 + 0.06
deductions = monthly_salary = hours_worked * hourly_pay

if monthly_salary < 4000:
    deduction_rate = deductions1
elif monthly_salary >= 4000 and monthly_salary < 8000:
    deduction_rate = deductions2
elif monthly_salary >= 8000 and monthly_salary < 16000:
    deduction_rate = deductions3
else:
    deductions = deductions4

net_salary = monthly_salary - (deductions * monthly_salary)
```

Comment: is deduction_rate suppose to be deductions?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It does exactly what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: gps answer is what I wanted, I'm an idiot for not noticing this. thank you guys regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this perhaps what you are trying to do?:

```
if monthly_salary < 4000:
    deductions = 0.12 + 0.04 + 0.01 + 0.06
elif monthly_salary >= 4000 and monthly_salary < 8000:
    deductions = = 0.20 + 0.07 + 0.03 + 0.06
elif monthly_salary >= 8000 and monthly_salary < 16000:
    deductions =  0.30 + 0.09 + 0.05 + 0.06
else:
    deductions =  0.38 + 0.11 + 0.07 + 0.06


net_salary = monthly_salary - (deductions * monthly_salary)
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm stupid lol

Comment: please vote if you think this answer was usefull - many thanks

Comment: I did, but since I'm new I'm getting this (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it, you do not need the lower bounds for elifs - the earlier if would have matched elsewise.

```
def getDeductions(salary):
    """Returns deductions based on given salary."""
    deductions1 = 0.12 + 0.04 + 0.01 + 0.06
    deductions2 = 0.20 + 0.07 + 0.03 + 0.06
    deductions3 = 0.30 + 0.09 + 0.05 + 0.06 
    deductions = 0.38 + 0.11 + 0.07 + 0.06  # default for >= 16k

    # lower deductions based on salary if less then 16k

    if monthly_salary < 4000:
        deductions = deductions1
    elif monthly_salary < 8000:        # lower border not needed, if would have matched
        deductions = deductions2
    elif monthly_salary < 16000:       # lower border not needed, if would have matched
        deductions = deductions3  

    return deductions



hours_worked = float(input("Hours:"))
hourly_pay = float(input("Pay per hour:"))

monthly_salary = hours_worked * hourly_pay

net_salary = monthly_salary - (getDeductions(monthly_salary) * monthly_salary)
print(net_salary)
```

Input of: `343` (h) and `12` (pay/h), Output:

```
2634.24
```

By factoring it out into a method you encapsulate the decision process away from your main code and make it "leaner". The specifics are clearly visible in your function.